# Car PA system enhancement

Tags: arduino-uno

Hello i have one of [these](http://gg.gg/hwrmi)

My goal for this project is to have a higher quality mic and be able to play music through it

My question is how would i link a 3.5mm aux cable to the arduino as input and output to the rj9 line. I have prior knowlege on liking a aux as i have setup my Christmas lights as a vu meter using relays and a aux but the confusing part is the rj9 line

Are the speaker pins only to trigger a relay and allow power to flow from the car battery or am i completely wrong if im right i assume i could just solder the audio jacks positive negative to the rj9 mic positive negative and then find a method to triger the speaker relay

Comment: your question about modifying the PA device is not related to an Arduino

Comment: Well assuming that my bottom portion was true the arduino was going to trigger the speaker if audio was comming off the jack there could be a better way though that would not require a arduino

Answer (score 1):

"how would i link a 3.5mm aux cable to the arduino as input and output to the rj9 line" - the arduino uno doesn't have a digital to analog converter, so without external hardware it's not possible to make him generate the audio signal. Also its ADCs are not fast enough to sample an audio signal coming from a microphone at a sufficient sample rate (I think the maximum are 1-2kHz). As you explicitly want to improve sound quality this is an issue.

When using an arduino uno you might be better off using an external audio circuit which only gets switched on and off by the arduino.
Controlling the siren's buttons will not be a big difficulty. You have to do some reverse engineering to find out the siren's logic level and how the buttons are used in the device. You can probably simply replace them with mosfets, but that is an electronic issue.

Comment: So even with a adc the standard sample rate being 44.1 khz i would need almost 30 times the current capabilities of a adc. I didnt realise that perspective thank you